# How to call procedure in PostgreSQL using SELECT?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I'm converting oracle to PostgreSQL. How to call another package in current package in PostgreSQL using SELECT.

oracle code:

```
SELECT * FROM pkg_beneficiary_sp_regenerate_otp(P_ENTITY_CODE, P_IMEI_NUMBER, P_USER_ID, W_OTP, W_ERROR) INTO W_OTP, W_ERROR;
```

I tried using code like this but it's not working

```
call pkg_beneficiary_sp_regenerate_otp(P_ENTITY_CODE, P_IMEI_NUMBER, P_USER_ID, W_OTP, W_ERROR);
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Postgres has no "packages". If `pkg_beneficiary_sp_regenerate_otp()` is a function you need to use `select * from pkg_beneficiary_sp_regenerate_otp(..)` in Postgres as well.

Comment: Sorry its procedure. In procedure pkg_beneficiary_sp_validate_otp. I'm calling procedure pkg_beneficiary_sp_regenerate_otp. pkg_beneficiary_sp_regenerate_otp ia separate procedure

Comment: Well, if it's a procedure then `CALL` is the right way, but that can't be used in a SELECT statement. Also "*it's not working*" is not valid Postgres error message. But why did you convert an Oracle _function_ to  Postgres _procedure? If it returns something, it should be a function.

Comment: I'm converting Oracle procedure to Postgres procedure. I have not used any function for this procedure.

Comment: how to call another procedure. That procedure output should be taken and stored in current procedure. Is it possible to do that using above code.

Comment: Without seeing the code an answer is not really possible.